# search amazon cognito users by custom attribute

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm developing a react native app which uses aws-amplify to interact with amazon cognito.  In my use case, I need to ensure value of a custom attribute is unique across all accounts.  aws-amplify does not seem to have an API which allows me to search across all accounts by a custom attribute.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately you simply can't using Cognito alone:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-manage-user-accounts.html#cognito-user-pools-searching-for-users-using-listusers-api

> Custom attributes are not searchable. This is because only indexed attributes are searchable, and custom attributes cannot be indexed.

Your only option will be to keep your own database relating the user to the attribute value, and enforce uniqueness there. For example in DynamoDB you would record the user's `sub` (unique Cognito identity) and the value of the custom attribute as sort/partition keys accordingly, ensure that normal cognito clients could only *read* the custom attribute, and provide your own API (lambda + api-gateway) to attempt to add/update the table and use the cognito Admin API to update the 'read-only' custom attribute on the user.

Comment: I wouldn't use API gateway in this case. I would use cognito 'PreSignUp_SignUp' lambda trigger to search on DynamoDB then reject the sign up in case of conflict.
Then I would use cognito 'PostConfirmation_ConfirmSignUp' lambda trigger to add the custom attribute of the user just created.

Answer (score 9):

That's correct you can't search custom attribute. Why can't you use one of standard attribute of AWS Cognito to be populated same as custom attribute. Just a thought. Then you can search also to check it uniqueness.

> Standard attributes:
>
> username (case-sensitive)
>
> email
>
> phone_number
>
> name
>
> given_name
>
> family_name
>
> preferred_username
>
> cognito:user_status (called Status in the Console) (case-insensitive)
>
> status (called Enabled in the Console) (case-sensitive)
>
> sub

Comment: By the way, it seems you can only search by these standard attributes and not all standard attributes. E.g. I don't see "profile" in this list. This list seems to come from docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html#API_ListUsers_RequestSyntax

Answer (score 2):

By using CLI you can do something like this to search custom attributes:

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id USER-POOL-ID --attributes-to-get "custom:ATTRIBUTE" --query "Users[?contains(Attributes[].Value, 'foo')]"
```